# Java: database connection. Where is my mistake?

Tags: java, sql-server, database, connection

Hy!

I really need your help. I'm trying to connect a database to a java program. This is my first time, so I have no idea what i'm doing.

My sql server: [Sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm0Sz.jpg)

I want to connect the Test database to the java program.

I tried the following code:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection conn = null;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:WIN2CNG9\\SQLEXPRESS:3306/Test", "win2cng9\\kmim1437", "");
    conn.close();
```

The error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:WIN2CNG9\SQLEXPRESS:3306/Test
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at javaapplication42.JavaApplication42.main(JavaApplication42.java:24)
Java Result: 1`

What is my mistake?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you're trying to talk to a SQL server, why are you making sure that an *Oracle* driver is present, and then using a *mysql* JDBC URL? You should really re-read a tutorial and make sure you understand what each part of the code does - if the right classes are in your classpath, you shouldn't need the `Class.forName()` call at all these days, but you do need an appropriate JDBC URL for your database.

Comment: Then what should I use?

Comment: Try to search the internet. Google is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class.forName("**oracle**.jdbc.driver.**OracleDriver**");

DriverManager.getConnection("**jdbc:mysql**:

Why your use Oracle driver with mysql database? Use following code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = null;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:WIN2CNG9\\SQLEXPRESS:3306/Test", "win2cng9\\kmim1437", "");
    conn.close();
```

Comment: I got the same error. is my string ok? I don't know what and where i have to write?

Comment: You string should be DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabase","your_user", "your_password"), so I think corect is something like this "jdbc:mysql://SQLEXPRESS:3306/Test", "win2cng9", "kmim1437", if understand what is your user, server and password

Comment: See, for example this guide http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/

Comment: Thank you for helping, and sorry for stupid question( oracle with mysql), but I have to start somewhere ;)

Comment: The OP isn't using mysql. They're using SQL Server. Oracle and mysql are both distractions, presumably due to cobbling together code from elsewhere without understanding it.